# Performance related articles on filesystems design and implementation

Tags: performance, caching, optimization, filesystems, inode

I'm looking for papers/group discussions/blogs on how various filesystem implementations handled their performance issues. I can't seem to find anything good and recent, that's why I probably don't have a good list in my head of what I'm really looking for, but just to give an example: what gets cached and why? and how? and which hash functions were tried and finally used? multi-threading related issues? - what gets guarded with mutexes and what's being kept atomic for the sake of simplicity? queuing related issues? There's probably more, but as I said, I'm just starting to look into it, so I'd appreciate any comments and suggestions. Thanks.